# Integration of an exponential function.

Tags: integration

How do we integrate $\int e^{(ax^2 + bx)} dx$

Actually what i really want to find the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{-\omega^2}$

Please explain both if possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the integral, start completing the square $$ax^2+bx=a(x+\frac b {2a})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$ So $$e^{ax^2+bx}=e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}e^{a(x+\frac b {2a})^2}$$Now, change variable $x+\frac b {2a}=t$, $dx=dt$ and so $$\int e^{(ax^2 + bx)} dx=e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}} \int e^{at^2}\,dt$$ which is a classical integral.

Comment: Just in case OP needs it, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{at^2} dt = \sqrt {\pi/a}$. And more information on this so-called Gaussian integral can be found on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: @suncup224. You are correct but this is only if $a<0$ I guess.